# What is the maximum file name length that can be used with the OneDrive SDK?

Tags: c#, sdk, onedrive, limits

When using the [C# OneDrive SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp) to create files what is the maximum file name length for new files?

Answer (score 0):

The limit is **256 characters** for the file name (without path).

Since I found no documentation about this I simply tested creating files until it worked.

For the record: this is the exception you get when uploading file contents via `PutAsync` while using a file name that exceeds the limit:

- Type: `Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.OneDriveException`
- Code: `invalidRequest`
- Message: Parameter Exceeds Maximum Length
- Inner error -> Code: [`parameterIsTooLong`](https://dev.onedrive.com/misc/errors.htm)

Note: Files with long file names will cause sync problems in the OneDrive client, since the limit there is lower (path + file name).